# How to create an associative list in Java?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am trying to have a user enter a `String` to search for a value in a list. This works fine, but I also want the `String` to have a numeric value. This way I can get the certain item in the lists price. I tried:

```
public List<String, double>
```

However this always gives me an error. How can I store strings and their corresponding numeric value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you only storing a `String` and a `Double`, or will you eventually need to store more information about each object?

For example, you're talking about storing a name and a price. If this is for a shopping-like program, you would probably be best to store all the information for each product in a new class, and then store the class in the `HashMap`. For example..

```
// Class for your product and all related information...
public class Product {
    String name;
    double price;
    String color;
    double weight;

    public Product(String name, double price, String color, double weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.color = color;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

// Now add each Product to a HashMap (in your main class)...
HashMap<String,Product> products = new HashMap<String,Product>();
products.put("Cheese", new Product("Cheese",1.10,"Yellow",0.5);
products.put("Milk", new Product("Milk",2.0,"White",1.5);
```

You will then be able to query the `HashMap` for `"Cheese"` and you'll get the `Product` and and all the information for it...

```
Product cheese = products.get("Cheese");
double price = cheese.getPrice();
```

Comment: Oh this is even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use a Map.

```
Map<String, Double> someMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

Then, you can use `Map#put(K, V)` and `Map#get(K)` to put and get values.

Check out the [Map documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) as well.

From Java 7 onwards, you can omit the generic type within the constructor's declaration:

```
Map<String, Double> someMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Map#get(k) will only take one parameter. i.e the key.