# How to create a table in Java?

Tags: java, database, dictionary

I want to create a sort of table in Java. I initially tried using a HashMap:

```
public Map<String, Double> namesAndPrices = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

This doesn't work when I want to add another String to it like so:

```
public Map<String, Double, String> namesAndPrices = new HashMap<String, Double, String>();
```

What class can I use to create a sort of table in Java where I can easily look up values and what not.

Answer (score 3):

Use objects, rather than trying to put unstructured data into collections.

Your map should be a `Map<String, Product>`, with the Product objects containing the name, price, and other properties of your products.

BTW, you were already told to do this in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966855/how-to-create-an-associative-list-in-java), and you even accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an object as the second parameter that wraps the double and string:

```
class Container
{
    public String str;
    public double dbl;
}

public Map<String, Container> container = new HashMap<String, Container>();
```

You'll likely want to use better names, not have public members, but hopefully illustrates the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're best off creating a custom object placeholder.

```
Map<String, Database> namesAndPrices = new HashMap<String, Database>();

public class Database {
    private double doub;
    private String str;

    public Database(double doub, String str) {
        this.doub = doub;
        this.str = str;
    }

    // getters
}
```